# ClassNotFound Exception in java

Tags: java

I have a simple Java program that uses joda-time-6.jar". I keep this jar in CLASSPATH and I am able to compile this program.

But when I try to run it using java command from the same directory inside where .class is located , I get ClassNotFoundException .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Fmo/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Fmo.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Fmo.class.  Program will exit
```

.

Can someone point out

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Fmo {

          public static LocalDate getNthSundayOfMonth(final int n, final int month, final int year) {
                  final LocalDate firstSunday = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY);
                      if (n > 1) {
                                final LocalDate nThSunday = firstSunday.plusWeeks(n - 1);
                                final LocalDate lastDayInMonth = firstSunday.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
                                if (nThSunday.isAfter(lastDayInMonth)) {
                                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no " + n + "th Sunday in this month!");
                                }
                                return nThSunday;
                      }
                      return firstSunday;
          }


           public static void main(final String[] args) {
                  System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(1, DateTimeConstants.MAY, 2014));
                  System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(2, DateTimeConstants.MAY, 2014));
                  System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(3, DateTimeConstants.MAY, 2014));
                  System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(4, DateTimeConstants.MAY, 2014));
                  System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(5, DateTimeConstants.MAY, 2014));
           }
}
```

Comment: Export it ? Did not get you . Can you please elaborate a little. I have that jar in my classpath path

Comment: show how do you run this java program? Is classpath complete and passed as argument to java?

Comment: Did you developed it in some sort of IDE?

Comment: It means `Fmo.class` is not present in the compile path

Comment: I am running it by doing java Fmo . My CLASSPATH contains only the jar path of jodatime. No, I did not develop it using any IDE.

Comment: can you share where your jars and java classes located? what is your command and CLASS_PATH ?

Comment: I compiled using "javac Fmo.java" with CLASSPATH contatining only the path of jodatime jar. When I try to run it using "java Fmo", then I get this error.

Comment: provide the classpath which you have configured

Comment: One thing is for sure. There's a problem in your class path. echeck whether the jar exists in the correct place and whether you are using the correct location while setting its path.

Comment: CLASSPATH is /home/username/joda-time-1.6.jar

Comment: Yes, if the jodatime jar is not included in my CLASSPATH it wont even compile because it uses APIs of that jar. If CLASSPATH is empty then it wont even compile.

Answer (score 1):

The `javac` and `java` commands handle the classpath slightly differently.  Specifically, since you pass in a file list to `javac` to be compiled you only need to include the location(s) of the libraries you need in order for the compiler to work.  On the other hand `java` expects your classpath to explicitly include `.` in order to run class files in the current directory.

Here's an example (run in Cygwin):

```
$ ls
JodaTest.java  joda-time-2.2.jar

$ cat JodaTest.java
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class JodaTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new LocalDate());
  }
}

$ javac -cp joda-time-2.2.jar JodaTest.java

$ java -cp '.;joda-time-2.2.jar' JodaTest
2014-05-15
```

Note that you could use `'.;joda-time-2.2.jar'` as the classpath for both commands, but only for the latter is the `.` is necessary.  You may also need to use `:` instead of `;` in your classpath, see [`File.pathSeparatorChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar) for more if your unsure.

You could just as easily use the `CLASSPATH` variable, rather than the `-cp` flag, however [this is not recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html):

> The preferred way to specify the class path is by using the -cp command line switch. This allows the CLASSPATH to be set individually for each application without affecting other applications. *Setting the CLASSPATH can be tricky and should be performed with care.*

Comment: I am able to compile the way you mentioned. But when I do java -cp '.;joda-time-jar' JodaTest  I still get ClassNotFound exception.